# Password was required when buying the theater tickets

Tags: password-policy

When buying the theater tickets in the site biletru.co.il I was required for the email address and its password. Why ? If it is dangerous to enter the password in this case ?

Comment: Password for what? Without any details I would assume that it is for an account on this site (pretty common) on not for the account and your email provider.

Answer (score 0):

Never enter your "work", or "personal" login information into anything but those portals for which they were created.    Always use different usernames, and passwords for each separate account you create for each separate website that requires it. If this website is asking you to create an account, that seems normal, if they are asking for other information, i.e. personal email information, that is not normal and likely a malicious request.